# CaptureStackBackTrace with file information

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using `CaptureStackBackTrace` and `SymFromAddr` to identify the functions in the callstack.
Is there a way to find the source file of each symbol with this (i can't find any documentation for this)? Or i have to use StackWalk ?

Comment: You need the debug symbols for the module, the .pdb file.  Use the DebugAPI.

Comment: I need the source file for the stuff that is represented by the symbol, not the source file of the symbol.

Comment: I think you'd be better off with StackWalk64

Comment: I spotted a function called SymGetLineFromAddr but it seems to fail. Still digging hopefully to a good result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to use `SymGetLineFromAddr` which gives the file path and the line number. In order to do this you must set `SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES` flag before calling `SymInitialize`. Also the 3'rd argument of `SymGetLineFromAddr` must be not NULL, otherwise it will crash.

Comment: Note you can set `SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES` from the [SymSetOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-symsetoptions) function